# Why memory away increasing when execute huge number Runnable in thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, threadpool

My workmate give me a code snippet like this:

```
public class Main1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

            Runnable runnable = () -> {
                try {
                    // business logic
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().toString() + ":" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                executorService.execute(runnable);
            }

            System.in.read();

        }

    }
```

In the above code, create 100000 Runnable instances. When I run this code, I can see heap aways increasing in JVisualVM, but 100000 Runnable instances memory size almost not change. My JVM opts is -Xms20m -Xmx20m -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1. Java version is 1.8.0_151, on macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6. All thread in thread pool are sleep, so Why heap aways increasing? What object are created?

JVisualVM Visual GC:
[image]

JVisualVM Sampler:
[image]

Comment: executorService.execute(new Runnable()...)...? That's creating a new Runnable() object 100k times in your for loop.

Comment: You are creating 100000 `Runnable` instances of the anonymous class.

Comment: When you replace Runnable creation with lambda, what do you see then?

Comment: Since your runnable doesn't keep any state, you can just as well create one Runnable and submit it to the pool 100000 times. the task queue will expand in size to hold 100000 entries but they will all point to the same object.

Comment: Yes, but do you actually have a _problem?_ (I.e., does the program throw an OutOfMemoryError if you let it run long enough?) You might be able to find different command-line options that make the JVM use less memory, but when you do that for a _real_ program (i.e., one that doesn't spend virtually all of its time in `sleep()` calls), you may find that the program runs slower as a result. Forcing the JVM to use less memory typically makes it spend more time collecting garbage, for example.

Comment: Key point is : why the memory used by `java` is increasing? can you state the java version you were using? the gc options too.  why not get a heapdump in visualvm and check what's going on there?

Comment: You don’t “create 100000 Runnable instances”. There is only one runnable. Further, the VisualVM screenshot doesn’t show any significant increments of the memory consumption. So what’s your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: Most of this garbage is created by VisualVM itself monitoring your JVM. It uses Java Serialization which is pretty inefficient. The best way to reduce the amount of garbage created is to reduce your polling interval. (Or use a profile which doesn't do this like JMC or YourKit)

Creating tasks uses memory, each node added to the work queue uses memory. A shorter and much more efficient way of doing this is to an `IntStream`

```
public class Main {
    static void doWork(int task) {
        try {
            System.out.println("starting " + task);
            // business logic
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println("... finished " + task);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream.range(0, 100_000)
                .parallel()
                .forEach(Main::doWork);
    }
}
```

This uses the same amount of memory regardless of the number of tasks by breaking up the tasks into the available number of processors (it creates only two actual tasks for every processor you have)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating 10.000 Runnable instances, while only 3 threads at a time can be executed, due to your Thread pool. It creates a large queue of Runnable instances which can not be executed yet.

Try to increase you Thread pool size, or decrease the number of Threads who have to be executed.